# How can I Load a class while startup tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I would like to load java class file that contain db related function. How can I load that java file while starting the tomcat server

Comment: have you tried using a singleton model for your db connection?? or static blocks?? what exactly is you issue with the thing you are trying to achieve??

Comment: Same way in which you refer to any other class file - you just refer to it and the JVM will load it when necessary.

Comment: I am using Quartz scheduler to schedule jobs.Once if we stop server,quartz related data will be gone. If I start the server again i  need  to get the job details from db and supply to scheduler method of submitted job details

Comment: Totally reading between the lines here .. but i think you mean, How do you cange Quartz to use a JDBC store from In memory 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633404/quartz-scheduler-what-is-the-diff-between-ram-and-jdbc-job-store

Comment: Set up Quartz to use a database. For example, using this help page here: http://teknosrc.com/how-setup-quartz-scheduler-server-with-mysql-database/

Comment: How to use JDBCTemplate in startupInitializer

Comment: public class StartupInitializer {
 public void init() {
}
}
@Erwin Bolwidt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use servlet for that as below, define into **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>YourServletName</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.abc.xyz.YourServletClassName</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

in **YourServletClassName.java** file you can write your code.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Did you ask about check authorization (spring-security) before your application load?

Comment: Actually i didn't get, What is the link between your actual question and login authorization, Please explain.

Comment: This is a pre-2001 solution. A generic solution for this would use a java.servlet.ServletContextListener. However it seems that the OP really needs to configure Quartz to do his dirty work instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Psabuwala is correct but not complete.
Code that will run on startup should be placed in the `init` method of the servlet.

Web.xml:

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>example.com.MainServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
```

MainServlet.java:

```
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        DataLoader dataLoader = new DataLoader();
        dataLoader.load();
    }
    ... 
}
```